# Перенос проекта между SVN-репозиториями

Tags: svn, репозиторий

Есть 2 SVN репозитория A и B.

Необходимо перенести SVN проект из А в определённую папку B, скажем, `/sites/projectA/trunk`.

Сделал копию репозитория А

```
svnadmin dump /var/svn/repositories/repoA > repoA.dump
```

Затем открыл файл с помощью NotePad++ и заменил`Node-path: trunk` на `Node-path: /sites/projectA/trunk`.

Подскажите, как правильно импортировать теперь этот файл в репозиторий B. При этом надо учесть, что в данном репозитории уже есть и другие проекты. Такое возможно?

Answer (score 2):

Делается всё очень просто.

Сначала нужно сделать дамп репозитория на старом сервере:

> `svnadmin dump /var/svn/project/ > /tmp/svn.dump`

Скопировать этот дамп на новый сервер:

> `scp /tmp/svn.dump user@newserver:/tmp/`

Создать новый репозиторий на новом сервере:

> `svnadmin create /var/svn/project/`

И, наконец, загрузить туда дамп:

> `svnadmin load /var/svn/project/ < /tmp/svn.dump`

Осталось только в рабочих копиях проекта сменить URL репозитория на новый. Сделать это можно командой:

> `cd /var/www/project/svn switch --relocate OLD_URL NEW_URL`

Старый URL репозитория можно узнать командой:

> `svn info`